# Unable to list s3 buckets, getting error like "AttributeError: module 'boto3' has no attribute 'client'"

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm getting the error like below:

```
AttributeError: module 'boto3' has no attribute 'client'
```

My python snippet is as like below

```
[ansible@ip-172-31-40-59 python]$ cat lists3buckets.py
#import boto3
#s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
#obj = s3.Object(bucketname, itemname)
#body = obj.get()['Body'].read()

#import boto3
#from botocore import ClientError
#s3 = boto3.client('s3')
#for bucket in s3.list_buckets():
#    print(bucket)

import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError
s3=boto3.client('s3')
for i in s3.list_buckets():
    print(i)
```

**Note**: I did try the commented code as well but had no luck.

My environment is Amazon Linux 2 machine and has boto3 and botocore already installed.

```
[ansible@ip-172-31-40-59 python]$ pip3 install boto3 --upgrade --user
Collecting boto3
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/85/c6/00e25614edf5ac025684bcc7af4c750187249ea7abbfc19dac05b95e83e8/boto3-1.14.22.tar.gz
Requirement already up-to-date: botocore<1.18.0,>=1.17.22 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from boto3)
Requirement already up-to-date: jmespath<1.0.0,>=0.7.1 in /home/ansible/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from boto3)
Requirement already up-to-date: s3transfer<0.4.0,>=0.3.0 in /home/ansible/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from boto3)
Requirement already up-to-date: urllib3<1.26,>=1.20; python_version != "3.4" in /home/ansible/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from botocore<1.18.0,>=1.17.22->boto3)
Requirement already up-to-date: python-dateutil<3.0.0,>=2.1 in /home/ansible/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from botocore<1.18.0,>=1.17.22->boto3)
Requirement already up-to-date: docutils<0.16,>=0.10 in /home/ansible/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from botocore<1.18.0,>=1.17.22->boto3)
Requirement already up-to-date: six>=1.5 in /home/ansible/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from python-dateutil<3.0.0,>=2.1->botocore<1.18.0,>=1.17.22->boto3)
Installing collected packages: boto3
  Found existing installation: boto3 1.14.17
    Uninstalling boto3-1.14.17:
      Successfully uninstalled boto3-1.14.17
  Running setup.py install for boto3 ... done
Successfully installed boto3-1.14.22
[ansible@ip-172-31-40-59 python]$ pip3 install botocore --upgrade --user
Requirement already up-to-date: botocore in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages
Requirement already up-to-date: jmespath<1.0.0,>=0.7.1 in /home/ansible/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from botocore)
Requirement already up-to-date: urllib3<1.26,>=1.20; python_version != "3.4" in /home/ansible/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from botocore)
Requirement already up-to-date: python-dateutil<3.0.0,>=2.1 in /home/ansible/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from botocore)
Requirement already up-to-date: docutils<0.16,>=0.10 in /home/ansible/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from botocore)
Requirement already up-to-date: six>=1.5 in /home/ansible/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from python-dateutil<3.0.0,>=2.1->botocore)
```

I'm executing script as below:

```
[ansible@ip-172-31-40-59 python]$ !p
python3 lists3buckets.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "lists3buckets.py", line 14, in <module>
    s3=boto3.client('s3')
AttributeError: module 'boto3' has no attribute 'client'
```

I fail to understand why a simple snippet should not work?

Comment: Try uninstalling boto3 and reinstalling it.

Comment: What OS is that?

Comment: Hi jelly I did that, no charm whatsoever.

Comment: Hi Marcin, It is Amazon Linux 2

Comment: How do you execute your script? It should be `python3 lists3buckets.py`

Comment: I am executing exactly the way you described it

Comment: Interesting...you mentioned that boto3 and botocore were already installed.  I just started an instance of "Amazon Linux 2 AMI (HVM), SSD Volume Type" (ami-016b213e65284e9c9) and it did not have those installed and did not have Python 3.

Comment: What I meant was I stalled AFTER VM provisioning. I installed them. Vanilla does not come with those client libraries.

Comment: I created new VM and it works there but not on this VM...